# How to use constructor to create array of objects?

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

a) I have an array of objects that look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "Account": "1111-000",
        "Desc": "Accrued - Payroll & Payroll Tax",
        "Amount": "-8,459.88",
        "Partner": "RAP",
        "FY": "2018",
        "PD": "10",
        "VNO": "abc"
    },
    {
        "Account": "2222-000",
        "Desc": "Accrued - Management Fee",
        "Amount": "-9,228.33",
        "Partner": "RAP",
        "FY": "2018",
        "PD": "10",
        "VNO": "dfe"
    },
    {
        "Account": "3333-000",
        "Desc": "Current Year Earnings",
        "Amount": "0",
        "Partner": "RAP",
        "FY": "2018",
        "PD": "10",
        "VNO": "bcd"
    },
]
```

b) I want to loop through each object and use a constructor to create an output like below:

```
gridinsert: [{
  value: "1111-000",
  command: "setGridValue",
  columnID: "17"
}, {
  value: "Accrued-Payroll & payroll tax",
  command: "setGridValue",
  columnID: "18"
}, {
  value: "-8,459.88",
  command: "setGridValue",
  columnID: "19"
}, {
  value: "RAP",
  command: "setGridValue",
  columnID: "20"
}, {
  value: "2018",
  command: "setGridValue",
  columnID: "12"
}, {
  value: "10",
  command: "setGridValue",
  columnID: "21"
}, {
  value: "abc",
  command: "setGridValue",
  columnID: "23"
}]
```

The JSON will always be in the same order as shown. So in the output, I basically have to extract the values and create an object for each value. I would need to create the `gridinsert:[]` for each object in the initial array of objects.

Comment: Are `columnIDs` related to the keys of the object? For example, is column id `12` related to the key `FY`?

Comment: @Shidersz columnID are NOT related to keys of the object. They are set values which must be same for all objects. There are 7 unique columnIDs and they need to be in this order. does that help?

Comment: @Shidersz sorry to add to my last, yes 12 is related to key FY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this you are looking for ?

Each input object gets mapped to an output object with a property `gridinsert` which is an array of objects built from each property in the input object.

The column IDs are mapped to the property names using an object:

```
const colIDs = {
  Account: 17,
  Desc: 18,
  Amount: 19,
  Partner: 20,
  FY: 12,
  PD: 21,
  VNO: 23
};
```

If the keys are not consistent, for example, if you have a mix of uppercase or lowercase keys and possibly errors in some keys, turn all of the keys to lowercase and add entries for common errors or synonym keys. Before accessing the map by key, make sure to lowercase the key.

```
const colIDs = {
  account: 17,
  desc: 18,
  description: 18, // this could be used instead of desc
  amount: 19,
  quantity: 19, // and this instead of amount
  partner: 20,
  fy: 12,
  pd: 21,
  vno: 23
};
```

The mapping is done using `Object.entries` and `map`:

```
const result = data.map(elem => ({
    gridinsert: Object.entries(elem).map(([key, value]) => ({
       value,
       command: 'setGridValue',
       columnID: colIDs[key.toLocaleLowerCase()]
     }))
}));
```

Here is an example:

```js
const data = [{
    "account": "1111-000", // lowercase
    "Desc": "Accrued - Payroll & Payroll Tax",
    "amount": "-8,459.88",  //lowercase
    "Partner": "RAP",
    "FY": "2018",
    "PD": "10",
    "VNO": "abc"
}, {
    "Account": "2222-000",
    "Description": "Accrued - Management Fee", // synonym key
    "Amount": "-9,228.33",
    "Partner": "RAP",
    "FY": "2018",
    "PD": "10",
    "VNO": "dfe"
}, {
    "Account": "3333-000",
    "Desc": "Current Year Earnings",
    "Amount": "0",
    "Partner": "RAP",
    "FY": "2018",
    "PD": "10",
    "VNO": "bcd"
}];

const colIDs = {
  account: 17,
  desc: 18,
  description: 18,
  amount: 19,
  quantity: 19,
  partner: 20,
  fy: 12,
  pd: 21,
  vno: 23
};

const result = data.map(elem => 
    Object.entries(elem).map(([key, value]) => ({
       value,
       command: 'setGridValue',
       columnID: colIDs[key.toLocaleLowerCase()]
    })
));

console.log(result);
```

If instead you want all the transformed properties of your input items in a single array, you can do this:

```
const result = data.reduce((acc, elem) => {
    const entries = Object.entries(elem).map(([key, value]) => ({
       value,
       command: 'setGridValue',
       columnID: colIDs[key.toLocaleLowerCase()]
     }));
    acc = [...acc, ...entries];
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Doing this however will result in clashes between properties having the same value.

```js
const data = [{
    "account": "1111-000", // lowercase
    "Desc": "Accrued - Payroll & Payroll Tax",
    "amount": "-8,459.88",  //lowercase
    "Partner": "RAP",
    "FY": "2018",
    "PD": "10",
    "VNO": "abc"
}, {
    "Account": "2222-000",
    "Description": "Accrued - Management Fee", // synonym key
    "Amount": "-9,228.33",
    "Partner": "RAP",
    "FY": "2018",
    "PD": "10",
    "VNO": "dfe"
}, {
    "Account": "3333-000",
    "Desc": "Current Year Earnings",
    "Amount": "0",
    "Partner": "RAP",
    "FY": "2018",
    "PD": "10",
    "VNO": "bcd"
}];

const colIDs = {
  account: 17,
  desc: 18,
  description: 18,
  amount: 19,
  quantity: 19,
  partner: 20,
  fy: 12,
  pd: 21,
  vno: 23
};

const result = data.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(elem).map(([key, value]) => ({
     value,
     command: 'setGridValue',
     columnID: colIDs[key.toLocaleLowerCase()]
   }));
  acc = [...acc, ...entries];
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this is good, but what if I keys are not consistent? i.e what its not always "account" or "desc"? The ids will always be consistent but the keys might not be that might break the colIDs[key] part, how can i tweak that?

Comment: Could you have key clashes ? account or desc leading to the same number ? if not, just add the appropriate property names in the object if you want to add more properties

Comment: I added an example for lowercase/uppercase problems, as well as additional keys

Comment: gridinsert has an array outside and it itself is inside an object, I want gridinsert to be the main array and everything else inside that. I am looking at the object.entries/map but can't figure what is actually creating the array and object outside of gridinsert?

Comment: You want a single big array with all entries in it?

Comment: columnid objects 17 to 23 needs to be in own array. then the next set in own array and so forth

Comment: @user2763557, I updated the first code snippet to ouput an array of arrays. If this answers your question, please consider marking the answer accepted.

Comment: thanks for your help. Just a quick question, in terms of algorithm, what kind would this be? Or in terms of time complexity

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be first generate a map between object `keys` and the columns `ids`, like this:

```
const mapKeyCol = {
    "Account": "17",
    "Desc": "18",
    "Amount": "19",
    "Partner": "20",
    "FY": "12",
    "PD": "21",
    "VNO": "23"
}
```

Then you can use `reduce()` on your array to generate the desired result:

```js
const input = [
    {
        "Account": "1111-000",
        "Desc": "Accrued - Payroll & Payroll Tax",
        "Amount": "-8,459.88",
        "Partner": "RAP",
        "FY": "2018",
        "PD": "10",
        "VNO": "abc"
    },
    {
        "Account": "2222-000",
        "Desc": "Accrued - Management Fee",
        "Amount": "-9,228.33",
        "Partner": "RAP",
        "FY": "2018",
        "PD": "10",
        "VNO": "dfe"
    },
    {
        "Account": "3333-000",
        "Desc": "Current Year Earnings",
        "Amount": "0",
        "Partner": "RAP",
        "FY": "2018",
        "PD": "10",
        "VNO": "bcd"
    }
];

const mapKeyCol = {
    "Account": "17",
    "Desc": "18",
    "Amount": "19",
    "Partner": "20",
    "FY": "12",
    "PD": "21",
    "VNO": "23"
}

let arrayOfGridInserts = input.reduce((acc, obj) =>
{
    let gridInsert = [];

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(
        k => gridInsert.push({
            value: obj[k],
            command: "setGridValue",
            columnID: mapKeyCol[k]
        })
    );    

    return [...acc, gridInsert];
}, []);

console.log(arrayOfGridInserts);
```